# Maple - Express Multivariate Polynomials in Specific Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, maple, multivariate-polynomial

I want to know if there exists a command in Maple that can show how a multivariate polynomial is expressed in the specific ideal, and show what this expression is.
ex:
$$D4 := a_0^3*a_4^3 - 12*a_0^2*a_1*a_3*a_4^2 - 18*a_0^2*a_2^2*a_4^2 + 54*a_0^2*a_2*a_3^2*a_4 - 27*a_0^2*a_3^4 + 54*a_0*a_1^2*a_2*a_4^2 - 6*a_0*a_1^2*a_3^2*a_4 - 180*a_0*a_1*a_2^2*a_3*a_4 + 108*a_0*a_1*a_2*a_3^3 + 81*a_0*a_2^4*a_4 - 54*a_0*a_2^3*a_3^2 - 27*a_1^4*a_4^2 + 108*a_1^3*a_2*a_3*a_4 - 64*a_1^3*a_3^3 - 54*a_1^2*a_2^3*a_4 + 36*a_1^2*a_2^2*a_3^2;$$
$$I2 := -a_0*a_4 + 4*a_1*a_3 - 3*a_2^2;$$
$$I3 := -a_0*a_2*a_4 + a_0*a_3^2 + a_1^2*a_4 - 2*a_1*a_2*a_3 + a_2^3;$$
$$P := PolynomialIdeal(I3, I2);$$
$$IdealMembership(D4, P); true$$

[we can use the command "IdealMembership" to make sure that the polynomial D4 is a member of the ideal P, but how can D4 be expressed in P, i.e., find the f, such that D4=f(I2, I3).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sel3r.png)

----------
I tried the command "split" and "factor", but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: D4 would be in the ideal generated by I2 and I3 provided there are appropriate polynomials R, S such that D4=R I2 + S I3. This doesn't require a "factorization" of D4. That is, I don't know why you are looking for one.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. I want to know what R  and S be like in this example and how to get the expression in general.